# Flyout menu - can scroll to bottom to show entire menu

Tags: css

I have a flyout menu for screens below `992px`, but the menu items extend below the screen. When you scroll, it’s scrolling the content behind the menu. I’m guessing it’s partly due to `absolute` positioning, but not sure how to make the menu scroll down.

Here is a link to the dev server http://phiaconcepts.devlocation.site

Answer (score 0):

You could have a condition which sets the `body` to `overflow: hidden` if the menu is open.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution..

I added this inside the max-width : 992px media query

```
.fixed-top{
  max-height:100vh;
  overflow:auto;
}
```